# How to check the Internet Connection periodically in whole application?

Tags: android

I am doing a application which uses the Internet Connection through out the application. If the internet connection is lost while using the application, the application is forcibly closing. To avoid this, if internet is not available i want to show a Alert message. How can i do this.
At the time of Login i am checking the connectivity using the below code. But how can i do this for whole application in background.

```
private boolean haveInternet(){
        NetworkInfo info = ((ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE)).getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (info==null || !info.isConnected()) {
                return false;
        }
        if (info.isRoaming()) {
                // here is the roaming option you can change it if you want to disable internet while roaming, just return false
                return true;
        }
        return true;
}
```

Thank you..

Comment: @parag Can u show me an example for that?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10603/discussion-between-parag-and-wolverine)

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You should make an `BroadcastReceiver` that will be triggered when the connectivity status has changed :

```
     public class BroadCastSampleActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.registerReceiver(this.mConnReceiver,
                new IntentFilter(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION));
    }
    private BroadcastReceiver mConnReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            boolean noConnectivity = intent.getBooleanExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_NO_CONNECTIVITY, false);
            String reason = intent.getStringExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_REASON);
            boolean isFailover = intent.getBooleanExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_IS_FAILOVER, false);

            NetworkInfo currentNetworkInfo = (NetworkInfo) intent.getParcelableExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_NETWORK_INFO);
            NetworkInfo otherNetworkInfo = (NetworkInfo) intent.getParcelableExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_OTHER_NETWORK_INFO);

            if(currentNetworkInfo.isConnected()){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Connected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Not Connected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    };
}
```

and then in your `AndroidManifest` you can check if you have connectivity:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Download source code - [here](http://paragchauhan2010.blogspot.com/2012/04/check-network-connection-using.html)

Comment: hey have you checked another RegisterReceiver method with signature (receiver,filter,Braodcastpermission,handler) ? my doubt is, what "broadcast permission" you will use if you had to use it for registering this receiver?

Comment: this one is flashing the toast outside the application too...what if we only want to implement in-application broadcastreceiver????

Comment: @RishabhSrivastava you have to unregisterReceiver broadcast receiver on Destroy app

Comment: @ParagChauhan How do we get to know that we are connected to `INTERNET` and not just to Network?

Comment: @Roon13 yes its only give Network status but for Internet you have to ping any url and check response code.

Comment: How to check internet connectivity after interval..?

Comment: Using timer you can achieve this