# BroadcastReceiver when wifi or 3g network state changed

Tags: android, android-service

I have an app which updates the database whenever the phone is connected to WiFi. I have implemented a `Service` and `BroadcastReceiver` which will run the `Service` (it will tell me what network is in use), but the problem is I don't know what to add in the `manifest` file to start `BroadcastReceiver` when the network state changes or when it connects to some kind of network

Answer (score 64, accepted):

You need

```
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED"/>
<action android:name="android.net.wifi.STATE_CHANGE"/>
</intent-filter>
```

In your `receiver` tag.

Or if you want more control over it, before registering `BroadcastReceiver` set these up:

```
final IntentFilter filters = new IntentFilter();
filters.addAction("android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED");
filters.addAction("android.net.wifi.STATE_CHANGE");
super.registerReceiver(yourReceiver, filters);
```

**WIFI_STATE_CHANGED**

Broadcast `<intent-action>` indicating that Wi-Fi has been enabled, disabled, enabling, disabling, or unknown. One extra provides this state as an int. Another extra provides the previous state, if available.

**STATE_CHANGE**

Broadcast `<intent-action>` indicating that the state of Wi-Fi connectivity has changed. One extra provides the new state in the form of a NetworkInfo object. If the new state is CONNECTED, additional extras may provide the BSSID and WifiInfo of the access point. as a String

Also, you'll need to specify the right permissions inside `manifest` tag:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
```

To check connectivity, you can use `ConnectivityManager` as it tells you what type of connection is available.

```
ConnectivityManager conMngr = (ConnectivityManager)this.getSystemService(this.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
android.net.NetworkInfo wifi = conMngr.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
android.net.NetworkInfo mobile = conMngr.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);
```

Comment: Can we also add a broadcast receiver to check data connection?

Comment: I think this only give us the connection changes in WIFI adapter. I want to be notified when the mobile data connection has changed.

Comment: Thanks iccthedral. As an alternative to the string literals passed to the filters, WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION and WifiManager.NETWORK_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION are the equivalent definitions in WifiManager.class.

Answer (score 5):

This is what I do to get notified when connection has changed.
You define a `BroadCastReceiver` to receive the broadcast.

```
public class NetworkChangeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo wifi = connMgr.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
        NetworkInfo mobile = connMgr.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);

        boolean isConnected = wifi != null && wifi.isConnectedOrConnecting() ||
            mobile != null && mobile.isConnectedOrConnecting();
        if (isConnected) {
            Log.d("Network Available ", "YES");
        } else {
            Log.d("Network Available ", "NO");
        }
    }
}
```

You also have to define that `BroadcastReceiver` in your manifest file and filter by `ConnectivityChange`.

```
<receiver android:name=".NetworkChangeReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
        </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Source [here](http://programmingtutorialz.blogspot.com.es/2013/07/android-broadcastreceiver-when-wifi-or.html)

Comment: Please, consider that starting with Android N the `android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE"` broadcast is deprecated. The documentation suggests to use `JobScheduler` or `GCMNetworkManager`

Comment: @Nicholas it's not deprecated. You just have to create the broadcast receiver within the code, not in the manifest file.

Answer (score 2):

To complement @Dantalian's answer. Starting with Android Nougat you should not declare your receiver on your Manifest because it will not receive the `CONNECTIVITY_ACTION` broadcast. You should instead register your receiver using the `Context.registerReceiver(Receiver, Intent)` method.

Link to the source [here](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/connectivity-monitoring.html)

Answer (score 2):

Declare the intent filter to pass to the broadcastreceiver

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION);
registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
```

In the broadcast receiver, check for EXTRA_WIFI_STATE;

```
private BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();

        switch (action)
        {
            case WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION:
                int extra = intent.getIntExtra(WifiManager.EXTRA_WIFI_STATE,0);
                if(extra==WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_ENABLED)
                {

                }//...else WIFI_STATE_DISABLED, WIFI_STATE_DISABLING, WIFI_STATE_ENABLING
                break;
        }

    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You should make an `BroadcastReceiver` that will be triggered when the connectivity status has changed :

Here Same question [How to check the Internet Connection periodically in whole application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10350449/how-to-check-the-internet-connection-periodically-in-whole-application/10350511#10350511)