# android 4.0 pattern for download/sync data

Tags: android

I have an application for android 4.0(android:minSdkVersion="14") with lots of SQLite tables that needs to download(not delete or send) new data from my server. At the moment the user has a sync button, however i would like to implement something that would synchronize automatically when 3G/Wifi is on and every 1-2 hour.

What pattern or best practice should i use? an Alarm thing, or a local service, or a remote service, or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend you read Chapter 19 of **Android Pro 4**( http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/programming/android/9781430239307/chapter-19-broadcast-receivers-and-long-running-services/navpoint-164 ) and then use the **already ready source code** from here http://www.androidbook.com/akc/filestorage/satya/documentfiles/3810/ProAndroid4_Ch19_TestReceivers.zip

I did this by using **Alarm** + **ALongRunningReceiver(=Broadcast Receiver)** + **ALongRunningNonStickyBroadcastService(Local Service)** + **LightedGreenRoom(Handles CPU partial_wake so it doesn't fall asleep)**.

Answer (score 0):

You need two things:

- An alarm (Have a look at tutorials about the AlarmManager) to run your code every 1-2 hours
- A broadcast receiver to intercept network events. (see for instance [BroadcastReceiver when wifi or 3g network state changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10733121/broadcastreceiver-when-wifi-or-3g-network-state-changed))

Make sure your code runs in his own thread, you don't want to execute anything heavy in the broadcast receivers. A good place to run such a code would be a service with his own separate Thread.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [service](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html) and a [broadcast receiver (for the wifi state, as mentioned above)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10733121/broadcastreceiver-when-wifi-or-3g-network-state-changed). Remember that polling a web-server every X times is a really bad experience in terms of battery usage. Try building a GCM web service.