# What event is triggered when WiFi connection of the peer device is turned off in android ecosystem?

Tags: android, android-networking

What is the event triggered when WiFi connection is turned off by the peer device. Is there any way that the host device gets a callback for example, onConnectionStateChange() or similar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[this example](http://silverballsoftware.com/android-monitor-wifi-state-with-broadcastreceiver) suits your need.

What you're looking for is call broadcast receiver.
basically, you create a custom broadcast receiver that will receive message on some actions.
you define those action in an intent filter :

```
IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
intentFilter.addAction(WifiManager.NETWORK_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION);
```

then register your receiver on this intent filter :

```
registerReceiver(wifiWatcher, intentFilter);
```

and your receiver will implement the onReceive method :

```
public void onReceive( Context context, Intent intent )
```

You'll have to check connectivity on this onReceive method using :

```
ConnectivityManager conMngr = (ConnectivityManager)this.getSystemService(this.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
android.net.NetworkInfo wifi = conMngr.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
android.net.NetworkInfo mobile = conMngr.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);
```

to do that, you need to add those permissions in your manifest :

```
<user-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<user-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
```

hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

The system triggers a Broadcast with:

```
 "android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED"
 "android.net.wifi.STATE_CHANGE"
```

check out this answer and see how you can capture it with a BroadcastReceiver:
[BroadcastReceiver when wifi or 3g network state changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10733121/broadcastreceiver-when-wifi-or-3g-network-state-changed)

Answer (score 0):

You need to register a Broadcast Reciever see the sample project [NetworkUsage Sample](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/managing.html)`com.example.android.networkusage;`