# Network type change in Android Mediaplayer (3G -> Wi-Fi)

Tags: android, networking, wifi, state, 3g

In Android MediaPlayer when enabling manually Wi-Fi (having 3G working), I get the stop of the MP3 stream. But without IO exception. So it stops, and I need the way to fire the restart of the stream in this case.
What's the best way to do this? Check the type of network from ConnectivityManager by timer and fire restart of MediaPlayer on change? For ex., test each N seconds, if the new network is WiFi and old is 3G or other, and if yes, call restart()?
Or it's consumptive way?
Something is here: [BroadcastReceiver when wifi or 3g network state changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10733121/broadcastreceiver-when-wifi-or-3g-network-state-changed)
Looks more complex.

Answer (score 0):

What device is this happening on? Check the buffering listener (log it if need be) and see if the percentage doesn't increase after the WIFI switch.

The one thing you CAN do now however is to listen to network connectivity and resume playback after a network configuration change.