# BroadcastReceiver Wifi disabled

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcast

I want my application to give a notification when wifi goes 'offline'.

I figured out the notification part. But I can't seem to figure out the 'wifi check'-part.
I read something about BroadcastReceiver but I can't seem to get it working. Any useful links? or example code? Tutorials?

Thanks in advance!

Updated with code. Its working but I need it to only give a notification when wifi goes offline.

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {        

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
    this.registerReceiver(this.mConnReceiver,
            new IntentFilter(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION));
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

private BroadcastReceiver mConnReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        boolean noConnectivity = intent.getBooleanExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_NO_CONNECTIVITY, false);
        String reason = intent.getStringExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_REASON);
        boolean isFailover = intent.getBooleanExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_IS_FAILOVER, false);

        NetworkInfo currentNetworkInfo = (NetworkInfo) intent.getParcelableExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_NETWORK_INFO);
        NetworkInfo otherNetworkInfo = (NetworkInfo) intent.getParcelableExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_OTHER_NETWORK_INFO);

        if(currentNetworkInfo.isConnected()){

        }else{
            showNotification();
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: This is a duplicate of [broadcastreceiver-when-wifi-or-3g-network-state-changed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10733121/broadcastreceiver-when-wifi-or-3g-network-state-changed)

Comment: I didn't see that question. Anyhow, I updated my question, it's different now I guess haha.

Comment: Then you need to start a new thread.

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this

```
In Manifest.xml
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

In your application Code:

public class BroadCastSampleActivity extends Activity {

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.registerReceiver(this.mConnReceiver,
            new IntentFilter(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION));
}

private BroadcastReceiver mConnReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        boolean noConnectivity = intent.getBooleanExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_NO_CONNECTIVITY, false);
        String reason = intent.getStringExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_REASON);
        boolean isFailover = intent.getBooleanExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_IS_FAILOVER, false);

        NetworkInfo currentNetworkInfo = (NetworkInfo) intent.getParcelableExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_NETWORK_INFO);
        NetworkInfo otherNetworkInfo = (NetworkInfo) intent.getParcelableExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_OTHER_NETWORK_INFO);

        if(currentNetworkInfo.isConnected()){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Connected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Not Connected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
};
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I only think this is specified for network connectivity. I need it to only react to the wifi connectivity. Any advice?

Comment: the code will notify when the wifi connection is setup. I think that was your original question

Comment: It's not working correctly. It gives a Notification on start-up, and when wifi connection changes to ON on or OFF. I'll add my code in the startpost. I need to only give a notification when the wifi goes off.