# How to catch on Wifi Change?

Tags: android

I'm developing an app without GUI. It should start it's service when Wifi button is changed(ON or OFF).
This is my manifest file:

```
 <receiver android:name="com.updater.wifitester.NetWatcher">
        <intent-filter  
            android:priority="100">
        <action 
            android:name="android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED"
            android:enabled="true"
            />

        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Here is the permissions that I gave:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

And I extended Broadcast receiver:

```
  public class NetWatcher extends BroadcastReceiver {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION.equals(intent.getAction())) {
                //check intents and service to know if all is ok then set bWifiStateOk accordingly
                Toast.makeText(context, "Wifi on", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
                Log.i("wifi_state_changed","wifi changed...");
            } else {
                return ; // do nothing ... we're not in good intent context doh !
            }
    }
}
```

But there is nothing in the log cat and no Toasts shown. What Am I missing?
Please help me guys...

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10733121/1739882

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<intent-filter>
       <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: The toast will be shown if connectivity is changed, right?

Comment: Its preferred to use Logcat to print better than Toast.