# What to do if I want a condition not be checked twice?

Tags: android

I am making a small project in which i am setting the wifi to disable if the battery is less than 30%. But if the user enables the wifi again i want it must not be disable again.
I did this whole work in service class
The code i used is...
Kindly give any suggestion. Your suggestions are very valuable for me..

```
public class BatteryService extends Service
    boolean checkwifi;
    WifiManager mainWifi;

    public void onCreate() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onCreate();
            checkwifi = true;
            mainWifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);    
        }


    if (level <= 30 && !isCharging) {
                    tts.speak(" Battery LOw Connect Phone to Charger",
                            TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
                    if (checkwifi) {
                        mainWifi.setWifiEnabled(false);
                        bt.disable();
                        closemobiledata();
                        checkwifi = false;
                    }
}
```

Update 1:

I found the problem, the problem is service is starting again and again
What to do so that service must not start again and again

```
public class BatteryService extends Service
        boolean checkwifi;
        WifiManager mainWifi;

        public void onCreate() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.onCreate();
              Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Service created", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                checkwifi = true;
                mainWifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);    
            }


        if (level <= 30 && !isCharging) {
                        tts.speak(" Battery LOw Connect Phone to Charger",
                                TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
                        if (checkwifi) {
                            mainWifi.setWifiEnabled(false);
                            bt.disable();
                            closemobiledata();
                            checkwifi = false;
                        }
    }
```

Comment: what you need is a Broadcast receiver to get notified when the Network connection type changes..see the following: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10733121/broadcastreceiver-when-wifi-or-3g-network-state-changed

Answer (score 0):

Create a receiver for `android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED` event. Use SharedPreferences to set `userEnabledWifi` to `true` if the wifi gets activated after you disabled it. In your service check `userEnabledWifi` before you disable the wifi. If battery goes above %30 again reset `userEnabledWifi`to `false` so you can disable the wifi if battery goes below %30 again.

Answer (score 0):

What's the difference ? You should be able to register a receiver for battery events in the service, the same way as you do with an activity. For example:

```
private final BroadcastReceiver mBatInfoReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver(){
@Override
public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent intent) {
    int rawLevel = intent.getIntExtra("level", -1);
    int scale = intent.getIntExtra("scale", -1);
    int status = intent.getIntExtra("status", -1);

if (rawLevel <= 30 && !isCharging) {
                    tts.speak(" Battery LOw Connect Phone to Charger",
                            TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
                    if (checkwifi) {
                        mainWifi.setWifiEnabled(false);
                        bt.disable();
                        closemobiledata();
                        checkwifi = false;
                    }
        // Do something
    }
};

public void onCreate() {
    registerReceiver(this.mBatInfoReceiver, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));
}

public void onDestroy() {
     unregisterReceiver(this.mBatInfoReceiver);
}
```