# Alert user when wifi network has changed

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-wifi, android-broadcast

I am working with Android. I have a service that is getting data from a wifi network. I would like to alert the user if they lose connection to that wifi address. I have been trying to work it out, and I think I have narrowed it down to using a BroadcastReceiver. Here is my implementation so far...

```
WifiReceiver receiverWifi;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

receiverWifi = new WifiReceiver();
registerReceiver(receiverWifi, new IntentFilter(
            WifiManager.NETWORK_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION));  
}

class WifiReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {


    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    //Does this get executed when the network changes?
    }
}
```

**Specifically, my question is, how can I edit my code to run in my service that will let the user know through a notification that the wifi they were connected to was lost or was changed?** Thank you for any help.

Comment: This might be useful for you.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10733121/broadcastreceiver-when-wifi-or-3g-network-state-changed

Comment: Thank you, it's useful as a reference for the manifest.