# android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE issues

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I would like to implement a listener to change the state of WiFi and mobile Internet

created a simple `BroadcastReceiver c` intent filter `android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE`

it works, but I've noticed that when you turn on/off my WiFi `BroadcastReceiver` receives two identical intent with a delay of about 100 milliseconds.

Why and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2):

please add this Intent Filter too..

```
<action android:name="android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED" />
```

this will notify you about the Wifi State (ON or OFF)

Comment: the boradcastReceiver can catch a lot of Intent Filters just check the data is returning..

Comment: I was looking at the same data

Comment: Intent: Intent { act=android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE flg=0x8000010 cmp=xxxxx/.APIv1.connection.NetworkStateReceiver (has extras) }
 Conectivity: true
 networkInfo: NetworkInfo: type: WIFI[], state: DISCONNECTED/DISCONNECTED, reason: (unspecified), extra: (none), roaming: false, failover: false, isAvailable: false
 InetCondition: 0

Comment: please check this example : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10733121/broadcastreceiver-when-wifi-or-3g-network-state-changed