# How to display dialog box if wifi connected and if wifi not connected in android app

Tags: java, android, android-wifi

I am trying to connect to a WiFi network from my Android app. I display the available WiFi networks in a `ListView`.

If I click on the network name, it displays a dialog box and connects to WiFi. Once the user has logged into the network, it should display a popup with the network details instead of prompting for a password again.

How can I do this?

```
TextView textView = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.apName);
textView.setText(accessPoints.get(i);
textView.setPadding(60,0,0,0);
textView.setOnClickListener(
  new View.OnClickListener() {   
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        final Dialog dialog =new Dialog(getActivity());
        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        Window window = dialog.getWindow();
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.password_dialog);
        final Button connect = (Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.connect);
        Button cancel = (Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.cancel);
        connect.setOnClickListener(
          new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
               list<WifiConfiguration> list = wifiManager.getConfiguredNetworks();
               for( WifiConfiguration i : list ) {
               if(i.SSID != null && i.SSID.equals("\"" + networkSSID + "\"")) {
                wifiManager.disconnect();
                wifiManager.enableNetwork(i.networkId, true);
                wifiManager.reconnect();               

                 break;
             }
            }
           }
```

Comment: Use Broadcast Receiver to achieve this Possible Duplicate [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10733191/5022983)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to see if wifi is connected in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3841317/how-to-see-if-wifi-is-connected-in-android)