# How to check internet availability in android on coming back to the application from phone menu

Tags: android

In my UI i check the network availability in a button click listner

```
NewButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(isInternetAvailable)
                {
                Intent intent = new Intent(FeaturedListActivity.this,
                        NewJewelsActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
                }
                else
                {
                    MyAlertDialog.ShowAlertDialog(FeaturedListActivity.this, "", "Check Network Connection.", "OK");    
                }
            }
        });
```

I check network availability using the following code

```
public boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
          ConnectivityManager connectivityManager= (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(getApplicationContext().CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
            return activeNetworkInfo != null;
```

Now my problem is when i start the app with the wifi  in off state the condition will work and will show the "check network connection" dialog. And now i press the center button of the phone and turn on the wifi and coming back to the screen from where i left.Now the wifi is in ON state and it still shows "check network connection".If i restart the app it will not show the dialog.How can i solve this?

```
}
```

Comment: Try to return true instead of return !=null

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use a broadcast receiver to get your app notified about the changes in the network state.

Comment: Thank you. This is what i wanted. I got some code snippet from this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10350449/how-to-check-the-internet-connection-periodically-in-whole-application/10350511#10350511

Comment: You are welcome broadcast receivers are the best when you want to get notified about a broadcast service such as change in a network state.

Answer (score 1):

When the user clicks on the OK button, you should close the dialog and direct him to the settings wireless and networks screen. You should do a `startActivityForResult`, and when the user comes to the Application again then `onActivityResult()` will be called where you can handle your code. In `onActivityResult()` you can again check if internet is there or not and if not there then simply display a toast. On the button click you can directly start the wireless settings screen using

```
 startActivityForResult(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIRELESS_SETTINGS),0);
```